# ASP.NET Routing - Route Constraint with database lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, routes, case-sensitive

I'm just starting out with C# and ASP.NET and have the following questions.  I am working with code adapted from a couple different tutorials playing with Northwind and have gotten this far.  The list of acceptable categories is currently hard coded in a string but I would like to look up the CategoryName in the database to verify that it exists.

Obviously the purpose of this is to ensure that users don't just type:
*www.domain.com/Categories/AnyUrlWillWork* and return a valid page.

Also does anyone have an tips of how they are dealing with capitalization issues since the routing is case sensitive? For example *Categories/beverages* should forward to *Categories/Beverages* ?

Thanks in advance for any assistance, and glad to be joining Stack Overflow.

```
//Complex contraint class
public class EchoConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public readonly string[] ValidMessages = { "Beverages", "Produce", "Confections", "Seafood" };

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string message = values["CategoryName"] as string;
        return ValidMessages.Contains(message);
    }
}


//Routes
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
                        "Category Route",                       // Route name
                        "Categories/{CategoryName}",            // Url pattern
                        "~/ShowProductsInCategory.aspx",        // Physical file
                        true,
                        new RouteValueDictionary            
                            {{"CategoryName", "Beverages"}},         //Sets default value if none is provided in URL
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {{"CategoryName", new EchoConstraint()}}
                           );
```

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial, btw? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Is this MVC? If so, why not route to a function, which will check the category name against your data store and redirect to an error page if such category doesn't exist?

```
public ActionResult Index(string catName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(catName) || !MyCategoriesDataStore.Exists(catName))
        return RedirectToAction("CategoryError");

    // Load category data to be used from View

    return View();
}
```

A WebForms solution would be:

```
    public class EchoConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private IRepository rep;
        public EchoConstraint(IRepository r) { rep = r; }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            return rep.GetCategory(message) == 0;
        }
    }
.
.
.
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {{"CategoryName", new EchoConstraint(myDataAccessRepo)}}
                           );
```

Where you pass an object of class implementing IRepository with your data access logic (using NHibernate, EntityFramework or your own DAL implementation). You need to return a bool value, and this is what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have not dived into MVC yet unfortunately.  That's my next step after catching up...I haven't played with ASP.NET since the 1.1 days so this is all new.  I am working off of this tutorial BTW:

http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050510-1.aspx

Comment: I think you should jump right into MVC. Routing in WebForms isn't as natural as it is there, and IMHO WebForms will die a slow death now that MVC is around.

Comment: I was considering it but I need to catch up on a lot of the basics and the training/classes I have are not covering MVC.  Once I get through them I'll be jumping on the wagon with ya.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a way to do this with WebForms too, see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for adding.  It is a little over my head, but that is what I get for jumping into this.  So far I have been reading this tutorial:  http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs and have created a DAL that returns the Category names ( categoriesAdapter.GetCategories();  )  but am not sure how to proceed and use it in this class.  I can bind to a control on a page however.

Comment: Just add another function to your DAL which will pull a category out of storage by its (unique) alias, and make sure an object is returned (if it isn't -- the category doesn't exist). In the code above I called it GetCategory.

Comment: Still poorly hacking away at this.  I'm stuck on creating a function that will work.  Any code hints on writing that?  Also do I need a specific namespace for IRepository?

Comment: No, that is the easiest function, really. Just make it use a correct SELECT statement and you are done. No specific namespace, but if you use another you'll need to add a "using" statement at the top of the file (the IDE will cry about this one, so don't worry).